# Problems with pivot point of objects in Unity from 3dsMax

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax

I'm trying to group some objects together in unity by creating new empty GameObject, zeroing its position, then dragging my children objects into it, my problem is that it's anchor position is far away from children positions, am I missing anything? please see the picture for clarification: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV4CX.png)

Comment: its children are planes made with 3dmax, my question is how can I change its pivot to be in the middle of the whole cube?

Comment: @GunnarB., I believe the fact that you can see the UI Canvas in that image, is just a coincidence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** set the pivot where you want, in 3dsMax and **only then** export it.

It's a basic, well-known problem in 3D engineering and games.

Regarding **how to change the pivot** in 3dsMax or other software. That's a question for that software, it's different in everything.  For example in Cheetah3D you press the button labelled

> Reset the pivot to here

I emphasize that you MUST change it in the model-making software, you can't do so in Unity and there is no workaround.

Note that if you just google

> "3dsMax set pivot model"

you will instantly find many tutorials on this.  [Example](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-3D3DB646-42A1-4B7D-9A32-9CCDD65DE357-htm.html).